# Stone-Weierstrass Theorem for Probability Distributions

Tags: probability

Is there a theorem that tells us that we can approximate a continuous probability distribution arbitrarily well using another probability distribution mixture? I am trying to show that a distribution, such as Cauchy, can be arbitrarily approximated using several Normal distributions.

Comment: Arbitrarily well in what sense?

Comment: If your criterion is total variation distance (roughly, $L_1$ distance), then there are results of this vein in the field of *density estimation*. For instance, see [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.3207) paper of Chan et al. (STOC'14), which shows that many classes of distributions (or mixture thereof) are well-approximated by piecewise polynomial densities.